# Jquery toggle not working / 2 classes (multiple class selector?)

Tags: jquery, css

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GwUmb/4/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger,.trigger-2").click(function(){
        $(".panel,.panel-2").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've been struggling to load panel-2 from trigger-2...I notice that .trigger and .panel behave (somewhat) as expected (I notice some css-style weirdness).

If I remove the .panel-2 and the .trigger-2 the code behaves perfectly...but otherwise it doesn't.

I was trying to replicate what I read here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_classes.asp .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option for you is to use a single class name for your links/containers. I have cleaned up your code a little bit and provided a hover function to display your links. It should be a good starting point for you. A CSS approach using lists may be an even easier approach...

working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/GwUmb/11/

updated jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                //global var to hold the current selected link
                var $link;

                $('.trigger').hover(function() {
                    $link = $(this);
                    //get position of clicked link
                    var linkPos = $link.position();
                    //position & display this links panel
                    $link.toggleClass("active");
                    $link.siblings('.panel').css({
                        'top' : linkPos.top
                    }).fadeIn(600);

                }, function() {//hide the panel on mouseout
                    $link.siblings('.panel').slideUp(600);
                    $link.removeClass('active');
                });

            });
            // end ready
```

Comment: @ lukeocom. Whoa! That's pretty slick...thanks for the CSS list tip...much obliged....

Comment: no worries! I have cleaned up the CSS for you too - http://jsfiddle.net/GwUmb/11/

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that no matter which trigger you click, *both* (or all) panels will be activated because you are selecting them both and calling `.toggle` on them.  There are many ways to solve this such as storing the corresponding index of the panel on the trigger as `data`, or using the index.  The latter may work well for you.

```
$(".trigger").click(function(e) {
    $(".panel").eq($(this).index(".trigger")).toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GwUmb/6/